# Почему возникает ошибка при удалении строчек из датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas

Возникает ошибка при удалении строчек из датафрейма при этом в jupiter notebook все работает, но при попытке запустить аналогичный код в PyCharm возникает ошибка.

```
 raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")
```

В чем может быть проблема, вот сам код:

```
    df_0 = df.loc[df['markup'] == 0]
    df_1 = df.loc[df['markup'] == 1]
    labels = (df['markup'].value_counts()[0])
    print(labels)
    print(df_1.shape[0])
    df_1.drop(labels=range(df['markup'].value_counts()[0], df_1.shape[0]), axis=0, inplace=True)
```